# Laravel 4: Path() no longer working after composer update

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I ran `composer update` on Laravel 4 just now.  I was trying to fix an issue with `Input::json()`, which had stopped working right after a previous `composer update`.  Now, `path()` returns an undefined function error.

Did Taylor change either of these?  Does anyone know the replacements for them if he took them out?

Comment: I need `Input::json` to gather the data from a Backbone call.

Comment: Url is the replacement for path.

Comment: I had to cast `Input::json` as an array and then access it's properties like you would that of any array.  I liked the old way better.

Answer (score 6):

JSON input has now been merged into `Input::all()` so you can use the same interface for JSON as Form Data input. Alternatively, you can access just the JSON with `Input::json()->all()`.

To generate URLs you now want the `URL` facade (see [Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php))...

```
URL::to('some/url')
URL::action('MyController@action')
URL::route('my.route')
```

To generate paths on disk (see [Illuminate\Support\helpers.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php))...

```
app_path()      // Path to 'app'
base_path()     // Path to project root
public_path()   // Path to 'public'
storage_path()  // Path to 'app/storage'
```